# How to post a c# Hashtable with nodejs to WCF (basichttpbinding)

Tags: c#, node.js, wcf, hashtable, complextype

I have to access a WCF with node js. In this WCF there is a function that has one parameter which is an Hashtable. I'm doing this by using the SOAP protocol.
I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without using XML. Simple variables types like integer, string, bool etc. are sent fine, but the Hashtable is not accepted.

```
var soap = require('soap');

var args = {
    account_id: 'xxxxx', 
    username: 'xxxxxx', 
    password: 'xxxxx', 
    dotComLogin: false, 
    _hashtableArg: {
        a: 'aaaa',
        b: 'bbbb',      
    }, 
    offset: 5, 
    offsetIterations: 10 

    };
var url = "http://localhost:55791/WCF.svc?wsdl";
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.requestJobId(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I know that I can use the wcf.js module for NodeJs, but I don't want to write XML SOAP messages. Is this possible?

Comment: your url has wsdl? is it valid?

Comment: What do you mean "without XML" and "don't want to write SOAP"? The service accepts nothing else. Your best bet is getting a generator that generates a nice client for you from the wsdl. On a sidenote: `HashTable` is a type that was superseded 12 years ago in .NET... are you sure you want to communicate with a service not properly maintained in the last decade?